# Recognize word with blank

Tags: python, string, list

I tried to code command line program. I split the command to "action" and "variable" with "split()".

```
command=input("$")
com_list=command.split()
action=com_list[0]
if len(com_list)==2:
    varible=com_list[1]
    if action=="setssid":
        ssid=variable
        print("Sucessfully Set SSID",ssid)
```

But if I enter a two words SSID name, it only recognize the first word. Like "MY HOUSE", it only recognize "MY" as ssid. How can I solve it?

Comment: Add some inputs and expected outputs. Can your action also be a multi-word?

Comment: No, it can be only one word

Comment: what about your typo "varible"?

Comment: With My House, your if block wont execute, as you're checking len(com_list)==2 which would be 3. Maybe use My-House to fit into your code?

Comment: Since your SSID will always be the last parameter, I'd just use rsplit(" ", 1) to split off the last parameter

Answer (score 0):

If the command never has spaces, you could do something like:

```
action, argument = command[:(i := command.index(' '))], command[i+1:]
```

If both your action and the argument to the action can have spaces, there's no way to know what's what, unless you have fixed list of command:

```
commands = ['blow up', 'build', 'sell']
command = 'blow up my house'
for c in commands:
    if command.startswith(c+' '):
        action, argument = c, command[len(c)+1:]
```

Or you could just put quotes around the parts that have spaces:

```
command = 'sell "my house"'
```

But that adds far more complications if you also have to deal with quotes inside the argument, so you're probably better off avoiding that, if you can at all.